# How to use ajax jquery cross domain post method

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

i am having a problem. i want to send data using another domain.

This is how i did but i gained zero success.  Hope expert will solve my problem

```
<script>
var url="http://domain/edit_0.xhtml";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.post(url,
        {
          css_sheet: "body",
          action: "edit_WAP2_sheet",
          hash: "a87691766060d24ebb69aa40e5f75f",
          submit: "submit"
         },
        function(data,status){
           alert("Status: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>

<button>Send</button>
```

When I use http:// it doesn't work. I want to set url as **http://domain/edit_0.xhtml**

I hope, I will find my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Step one would be to structure your `$.post()` statement correctly. (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

As `$.post()` is just a subset of `$.ajax()`, I've written out the parent statement below to help guide you in the right direction.

```
var url="http://domain/edit_0.xhtml";

var datastring = "?css_sheet=body&action=edit_WAP2_sheet&hash=a87...75f&submit=submit";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: datastring,
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(e) {
        alert(e.responseText);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
    }
});
```

Added success and error functions to help you debug and maybe be a little less vague than "it doesn't work"

Also, for due diligence, review guidelines for cross-domain with AJAX (http://zinoui.com/blog/cross-domain-ajax-request)

#### Updated Error Handling

Create some div with `id="result"` to show error debug, and view console log more more details.

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('#result').html('<p>status code: '+jqXHR.status+'</p><p>errorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>'+jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
    console.log('jqXHR:');
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log('textStatus:');
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log('errorThrown:');
    console.log(errorThrown);
}
```

Comment: http://f23.wapka-files.com/download/4/d/2/2280890_4d2febb62b7c815057d40acb.png/bed99befdabb27db50a0/Screenshot_2015-12-28-23-26-35.png here is the image

Comment: Try replacing error function with this updated code above

Comment: Demo: http://simg.gq here is my form <form
method="post" action="edit_0.xhtml">
Own CSS styles in external file: <br><textarea
name="css_sheet" rows="5"></textarea>
<br><input type="hidden" name="action"
value="edit_WAP2_sheet">
<input type="hidden" name="hash"
value="a87691766060d24ebb690bbeccbb61">
<input type="submit" name="submit"
value="Set"></form> plz fix it 

Comment: Noting the following issue in your console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://waybay.wapka.mobi/edit_0.xhtml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://simg.gq' is therefore not allowed access.
you may want to try adding the `crossDomain: true` attribute to your `$.ajax()` call. I've updated the code block above.

Comment: same result.  Sir, i want to post data from simg.gq to waybay.wapka.mobi using any formula.  i have given the form elements.  Please solve it.

Comment: Some information, this is a tool for administration.  here hash value is a unique code, only admin of waybay.wapka.mobi can get it.

Comment: You may want to look into CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS